# What would be the best way of implementing classes and abilities for an RPG game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on a little 2D RPG game in Unity. The main idea is that the player can have multiple "classes" in their inventory. I'm not talking about class objects, in code, but the typical RPG classes like warrior, rogue, thief, mage etc. The player should be able to switch to whatever class they wanna use, whenever they wanna use it. All of the classes are different from eachother. They all have 3 passive bonuses, and 4 abilities/spells, and spells can vary a lot. That being said, I'm struggling to see a way on how to program these classes and their corresponding skillsets in a way that makes the most sense and uses the least amount of computer resources. I was thinking of using C# classes(object classes) for this, but it would be difficult to use inheritance as in-game classes have very different bonuses and abilities. I thought I could have a class that stores all the variables that abilities have in common, such as mana usage and cooldown. But how can I program these abilities without having 50 different classes?

Does anybody have design ideas on how to structure this, or will I have to create a whole class per in-game class?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you only need one class: RpgClass. Remember: classes model *behavior*, not *data*. Why would a Range Rover require a different C# class to store its properties than a Ferrari? They have different engines, different tyres, different characteristics, but none of those require inheritance.

So you'll have a class RpgClass (or think of something better), which has properties like `Name`, `Spells`, `Abilities`, `Bonuses` which you fill at runtime with different instances of strings and objects.

Then you'll have the classes `Spell`, `Ability`, `Bonus` and do the same thing again. Only when their *implentation* differs, you'll start subclassing.